# Passing parameters in URL calling Lizmap

Tags: postgis, lizmap

Is there a way to pass parameters in the URL, so that Lizmap could retrieve data from a Postgresql database and display it on a project map?
Actually I only found the a way to zoom to a location by passing the lat, lon coordinates  at a defined zoomlevel:

```
https://mydomain.com/lizmap/index.php/view/map/?repository=myrepository&project=myproject&lat=49.611295&lon=6.129441&zoom=8
```

Is there a way to implement a seach-function, that could pass schema, database and search string via url to grab data from PostgreSQL and display the searchresult highlighted on top of the existing project map?

So something like:

```
https://mydomain.com/lizmap/index.php/view/map/?repository=myrepository&schema=myschema&table=mytable&where=mywherestring
```

Comment: Actually, this is not possible out of the box. But indeed it would be nice to have additional URL parameters for searching with arbitrary search providers. Like in QWC2, where this feature is already implemented (https://github.com/qgis/qwc2-demo-app/blob/master/doc/QWC2_Documentation.md#url-parameters). Better ask for this feature here: https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-web-client/issues

Answer (score 2):

I have used one of the [lizmap example project](https://demo.lizmap.com/lizmap/index.php/view/map/?repository=feat1&project=observatoire).

You can set url to get only filtered data shown. To use filter you have some condition. The layer attribute table as to be accessible it activate a data menu with a filter option.

The structure is :

```
https://demo.lizmap.com/lizmap/index.php/view/map/?repository=feat1&project=observatoire&filter=LAYERNAME:"FIELDNAME" IN ( SPACE+VALUE+SPACE+COMMA )
```

Replace :

- `LAYERNAME` with your layer name. Only layer where the attribute table access is activated
- `FIELDNAME` with your field name. I think you can only use unique id field.
  and SPACE+VALUE+SPACE+COMMA to replace)
  For SPACE+VALUE+SPACE+COMMA you need space and comma to make it work (example :  `36 , 24 , 12`. All this will be modified by URL constructor.

Here is an example link :

[https://demo.lizmap.com/lizmap/index.php/view/map/?repository=feat1&project=observatoire&filter=observation:"id_obs" IN ( 35 , 38 , 39 )](https://demo.lizmap.com/lizmap/index.php/view/map/?repository=feat1&project=observatoire&filter=observation:%22id_obs%22%20IN%20(%2035%20,%2038%20,%2039%20))

You should get this :
[image]

**Warning :** The link with filter remain always active.

Comment: Great Corentin. I've tried Your suggestion, but my layer is only filtered in the detail tap of the data menue in Lizmap. On the map all data is still visible.

Comment: after a filtering operation (or selection) can you try the permalink tool and share the link (without your server and repo name).

Comment: Here is the permalink (with 'ourserver'):   `https://ourserver.com/lizmap/index.php/view/map/?repository=xfn&project=xfn_lizmap&filter=v_parcels%3A%22id%22%20IN%20(%2054%20,%2055%20,%2056%20)&layers=B0000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFTFFTFT&bbox=623001.498075%2C6385970.975234%2C742472.573268%2C6443451.620496&crs=EPSG%3A3857&layerStyles=v_parcels%3Adefault`

Comment: You can use this url as a base where you can delete some argument : the &bbox... the &layers... the &crs... the &layerStyles... . And add more element in the filtering formula url. `https://ourserver.com/lizmap/index.php/view/map/?repository=xfn&project=xfn_lizmap&filter=v_parcels%3A%22id%22%20IN%20(%2054%20,%2055%20,%2056%20,%2053%20,%2052%20,%20516%20)` to keep ònly id = 51 to 56

Comment: Ok, this is what I initially did, but I still have the same problem, that ALL parcels of the layer v_parcels are displayd in the map. When I open the data menue in lizmap and look at the details, I only see the attribute table of the filtered features. But on map I still see them all. (I've tried it with version 3.4.7 of Lizmap).

Comment: Oh strange... When you create the permalink all the parcels are visible or only the one filtered ? Are you sure that in your lizmap project the layer used for data table is the same that the one you can see in the map (no duplicate ?)

Comment: All parcels are visible when using the permalink. The parcels layer is not duplicated, nor in QGIS, nor in Lizmap, so that the data table reflects the filtered features, but not the map. The concerned layer is a polygon layer, but after my opinion this shouldn't be the problem. I'll try with other layers in that project to see the results.

Comment: Thanks. As the behaviour in your project is different than the one in the lizmap example i don't know how to deal with. May be an issue in lizmap github refering to stack.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post this on Lizmap Github.

Answer (score 0):

Work fine also with LIKE operator and wildcard *

[&filter=basesrtk:"mp" LIKE 'NCY'](https://centipede.fr/index.php/view/map/?repository=cent&project=centipede&filter=basesrtk%3A%22mp%22%3D%27NCY%27&layers=0B00TTTTTTFT&bbox=497103.271839%2C5687532.732334%2C879288.413212%2C5865783.882271&crs=EPSG%3A3857&layerStyles=buffer%3Ad%C3%A9faut%3Bbasesrtk%3Ad%C3%A9faut&filter=basesrtk:%22mp%22%20LIKE%20%27NCY%27)

Find only mp equal to **NCY**

[&filter=basesrtk:"mp" LIKE 'N*'](https://centipede.fr/index.php/view/map/?repository=cent&project=centipede&filter=basesrtk%3A%22mp%22%20LIKE%20%27N%25%27&layers=0B00TTTTTTFT&bbox=-1106853.66681%2C5251919.788483%2C1950627.464172%2C6677928.987973&crs=EPSG%3A3857&layerStyles=buffer%3Ad%C3%A9faut%3Bbasesrtk%3Ad%C3%A9faut)

Find all mp starting by **N**